# Python: A variable which is assigned and not changed changes along with another

Tags: python, initialization, sage

Working in Sage which is basically python, I believe. I gave the following code.

```
def lfsr_1(regs,tabs):
    I=regs
    leng=len(I)
    count=0
    while True:
        FB=0
        print "Before"
        print I
        print regs
        print temp
        for i in range(0,leng):
            FB=FB+tabs[i]*I[i]   //Calculating the feedback value
        for i in range(0,leng):
            regs[leng-(i+1)]=regs[leng-(i+1)-1] //Shifting regs one bit to the right
        I[0]=FB   //Adding the feedback at the end
        count=count+1  //Incrementing count value which will contain the periodicity
        print "After"
        print I
        print regs
        print temp
        if (I==regs):   //End when the initial state is repeated again. Now, count will contain the periodicity
            break
```

The input variables were in initialized as follows

```
tabs=[GF(2)(1),0,0,1,1,1]
regs=[GF(2)(0),1,1,0,1,1]
temp=regs
```

However, Im getting an output as:

```
Before
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
After
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Dont know how this happens as 'I' changes along with 'regs'. 'I' is never changed in code. Is there something wrong with my assignment?

Addendum:Trying to implement a Linear Feedback Shift Register. The code is to calculate the periodicity of an LFSR. regs is the intial state, I is used to check when the regs returns to the initial state again(to calculate periodicity) and temp is just a test variable to see if another initialized variable would also be shifted.

Comment: If you would give some information on what your end goal is here, as well as comment your code, it would make it a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Of course `I` changes along with `regs` because you made this assignment:

```
I=regs
```

Now `I` and `regs` reference the same list.  That is how Python works.  A list variable simply *references* a list object, it doesn't contain the whole list object.

Here's an example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = a
a[1] = 100
print b
```

Perhaps you wanted to make `I` be a *copy* of `regs`.

Try:

```
I = regs[:]
```

Of course, you might have "structural sharing" if `reg` contains objects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the line

```
I=regs
```

When you do this, you do not copy the *contents* of `regs`, you copy the *reference* to `regs`. Thus making `I` and `regs` the same array.